# Transplanting Edge v101 session with all its open tabs to another computer

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, microsoft-edge, migration, tabs

I had a very intense work period on a loaner laptop with multi-tasking between multiple projects, and I have literally hundreds (perhaps thousands) of tabs open in Edge browser (Edge is pretty good at unloading inactive tabs from RAM, so performance is decent even with with hundreds of open tabs).

I need to return this loaner computer, and I absolutely need to back up and move these open tabs to a new computer. Saving each tab tediously and then opening (as tediously) is not feasible and would also break the current work flow (each tab is in its appropriate window, each window in its appropriate place in the task bar). Saving to Collection or sending tabs via Sync one by one is also not feasible.

I have the "Re-open tabs from previous session" setting checked, so when I close Edge, it saves all these tabs somewhere. And then when I open it again, it restores my session precisely. I want to move whatever files Edge saves its state inside to a new computer and resume my work like nothing has changed. I used to be able to do it in Firefox.

I am using a recent (v 101) version of Chromium Edge. I know that many things that it saves upon exit are stored in SQLite databases. I am worried that transplanting the profile files might not necessarily work if the stored session along with its access to those component DBs is tied to the current Windows Account for privacy and security reasons.

So, my question is: Can I move Edge v101 profile files to another computer in such a way that upon starting Edge on that computer all my tabs and windows just reopen without any loss?

Comment: Try using [Tab Session Master - Microsoft Edge Addons](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/tab-session-master/bdpjmdkfckcdhlfnafglgkikcomfanho) - it has an export/import feature.

Comment: Have you just tried transferring the chromium based profile? However, in my experience, saving the session with an extension then transferring it will be more successful. I also have hundreds of tabs, been burned by just doing what you have done, several times now.